# 404 page being redirected to home page in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have this in my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The website needs this in order to run properly. When I place an incorrect url (non existent page) it redirects me to the home page? I want to display my 404 page instead?

Comment: How do you distinguish between correct and non existent URLs?

Answer (score 0):

If your 404 page is an actual file (e.g. /404.html) then the rule should work as-is since it specifies not to apply it to existing files. If your 404 page is virtual then you'll need to add a RewriteCond to exclude it. For example, if the 404 page is really `/index.php?error` you would add the following RewriteCond in front of the RewriteRule, updating the query string as needed:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^error`

Alternately, you could just make a real 404.html page for your php/CMS code to use, in which case the original rule should be okay.

Comment: I placed a 404.html page in my root directory and still if I enter a non existing url, I get redirected to the home page. Any ideas?

Comment: If you directly load the URL `http://(yourwebsite.com)/404.html` in your browser, are you redirected? If not, then how is your php code calling the 404 page? If you are being redirected, then the `-f` test is failing and you should try a specific `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.html [NC]`. if the `-f` test is failing, however, then that suggests another problem ... perhaps REQUEST_URI rather than REQUEST_FILENAME, though they should be equivalent here.

Comment: if I go to http://(yourwebsite.com)/404.html it loads the correct page. If I place http://(yourwebsite.com)/40klfjsdlkfjsdkl it sends me to the home page.

Comment: So the rule is working, then, in terms of keeping the 404 page from redirecting. Your php code must not be calling the 404 page in a way that Apache sees the URL as /404.html. You'll need to look at how that call is made.